# MFMailComposeViewController and cancelling "save" action sheet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, save, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i am using MFMailComposeViewController inside my iphone app. I notice that if i enter any text in the body and then press the cancel button, i am prompted with an action sheet with an option to save/don't save the unsent message. I have two questions:

1. can I programmatically prevent the "save/don't save action sheet from appearing? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate doesn't appear to have anything along those lines
2. if i do save, where is the mail saved to? i looked in my mail accounts and didn't see anything saved in any of the "draft" folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you can't avoid the action sheet appearing. It's been added in iOS 4.x to, precisely, avoid tapping on the "Cancel" button inadvertently when writing a long email, which I think it's a good idea.
2. It is saved in "Drafts" folder of the account used to compose the e-mail (normally, your "default account" as it is registered in the Settings of your device). I've just tried using a couple of apps and it works.